# Server app freezes with GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

This is my server script when running it without GUI the start method only it works fine but when running the whole script and I press the start button it just freezes and not responding and nothing appears on the text window

```
from Tkinter import *

import socket
import sys

class Application(Frame):

def __init__(self, master):

    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):

    self.text = Text(self, width = 35, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
    self.text.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    self.submit_button = Button(self, text='start', command = self.start)
    self.submit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

def start(self):

    self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.text.insert(0.0, 'Server started!\n' )
    self.s.bind(('',1080))
    self.s.listen(10)

    while True:
        sc, address = self.s.accept()
        i=1 
        f = open('file_'+ str(i)+".txt",'wb') #open in binary
        i=i+1
        while (True):       
            l = sc.recv(1024)
            while (l):
                print l 
                f.write(l) 
                f.flush()

        f.close()

        sc.close()


root = Tk()
root.title("Server")
root.geometry("500x250")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: your indentation is messed up, it's impossible to know what your script is actually doing.

Comment: i am doing a server that receives a file

Answer (score 1):

The only way for a GUI to work is if its event loop is able to service events such as those that respond to requests to redraw itself, respond to buttons, etc. In Tkinter, this event loop is `mainloop`.

When you click the start button you run no less than two infinite loops inside this event loop, which essentially freezes the event loop as long as these inner infinite loops are running.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand your explanation

Comment: it freezes even without the while loops 
the line  `sc, address = self.s.accept()` seems to be the problem the script it should write server started then wait for client to connect but it freezes instead

Comment: if the while loops is the problem it should write the sentence server started then freeze but it doesn't pass even this line